# How do I import another file in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

So I'm trying to import another file in JS and I keep getting errors. The main file is `script.js` and I'm trying to import `CookieManager.js`. I first tried using

```js
var cookies = require('/CookieManager.js');
```

but that caused this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. I found out that this happends because `require` is only supported by Node.js and therefore is causes an error when trying to run it in a browser. I then tried using

```
import {getCookie} from "../CookieManager";
```

and set it as an export function which caused this:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

. To fix that, I changed the type of the file from `text/javascript` to `module` in HTML. This happened: `net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. Finally, I tried using

```
JQuery (`$.getScript('/CookieManager.js', function()`)
```

but that also resulted in an error:

````
jquery.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:63342/CookieManager.js?_=1591679474637 404 (Not Found)```
````

Comment: How does your directory structure look like?

Comment: Using import and export and then using script tag with type 'module' in HTML should work. On 404, just try to give correct relative path.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HbICURO

Answer (score 0):

Try:

In `package.json` add:

`{"type": "module"}`

Then in `CookieManager.js`:

`export function GetCookie() { // your code to import}`

Then `script.js`:

`import { GetCookie } from '../CookieManager.js';`

Comment: This also causes a 404 error: `GET http://localhost:63342/CookieManager.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: put the actual path in `s.src`

Comment: If there is still any error open the folder and right click while holding shift on empty space and click on powershell or command prompt and type `tree` and press enter and share the output.         ( I am assuming that you are running Windows )

Comment: put CookieManager.js inside home page then try the   above or put `s.src='../CookieManager.js '`

Comment: That worked, but it's no longer allowing me to use `require` in CookieManager.js anymore. How do I import `js-cookies`?

Comment: are you using node.js or javascript in CookieManager ?

Comment: require is used in node.js.

Comment: I'm using Node in CookieManager yes. Is there a way I can import it without using `require`?

Comment: and script.js is node.js or javascript?

Comment: `script.js` is regular JS.

Comment: while trying to use `export` what was the src of script?

Comment: /HomePage/script.js

Comment: do the same as you did before and try:`import {getCookie} from "../CookieManager.js";`

Comment: But how do I import the js-cookie library into CookieManager.js?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the directory structure:

```
├───HomePage
│   ├index.html
│   ├style.css  
│   ├script.js
├CookieManager.js
```